# Logging to XCODE in PhoneGap 3.3 for iOS with AngularJS

Tags: ios, xcode, angularjs, cordova, phonegap-plugins

There are already several questions on SO about logging to XCode in a phonegap project (e.g. [console.log not working in an iOS PhoneGap 3.0 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183295/console-log-not-working-in-an-ios-phonegap-3-0-app)), but I cannot find any that use angularjs.

I have added the console plugin via

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.console
```

As suggested at the answer above I also tried the steps mentioned in [How do I integrate the PhoneGap debug console with CLI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645458/how-do-i-integrate-the-phonegap-debug-console-with-cli)

I am using the angular phonegap generator https://github.com/dsimard/grunt-angular-phonegap

When I run on the emulator via XCode (with no modificaitons except or adding console.log statements in app.js and controllers/main.js and the function suggested in the link above), I get the following output:

```
2014-01-24 18:59:07.162 MyApp[89948:70b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0xa790140 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/GeoServices.axbundle> (not loaded)
2014-01-24 18:59:07.170 MyApp[89948:70b] Cannot find executable for CFBundle 0xa7c3b80 </Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk/System/Library/AccessibilityBundles/CertUIFramework.axbundle> (not loaded)
2014-01-24 18:59:07.206 MyApp[89948:70b] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2014-01-24 18:59:07.211 MyApp[89948:70b] Unlimited access to network resources
2014-01-24 18:59:07.331 MyApp[89948:70b] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2014-01-24 18:59:07.440 MyApp[89948:70b] Finished load of: file:///Users/thisguy/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/1C7F417E-347B-4262-9969-38CE9D475C05/MyApp.app/www/index.html#/
```

I was worried about the line indicating that plugins are reloaded (and myabe the console plugin isn't? or something?), but according to the following edited answer, this may not (?) be a concern https://stackoverflow.com/a/21207066/1449799

Thanks to @MGyveR_ on #phonegap I learned that my logs are at least visible through Safari's Web Inspector when I am running in the iPhone Simulator. Still not sure why they're not in XCode console.

Answer (score 3):

I too was having the same problem. It turned out that `deviceready` function for the logger was not getting called. The final line in `logger.js`.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", logger.__onDeviceReady, false);
```

The solution (or really a work-around) is to call the `logger.__onDeviceReady` function from your `deviceready` listener function:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    if (window.cordova.logger) {
        window.cordova.logger.__onDeviceReady();
    }
}

document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
```